# Something in Windows is preventing screensaver and monitor stand-by

Tags: windows-7, windows, screensaver, standby

Since I have this computer (it's a normal machine: an I5 on a P7P55D, HD5700 graphic board) Windows 7 has never been able to start screensavers or put monitors in stand-by. Configuration is not the problem, because even with "nircmd monitor off" or "wizmo", monitors go blank for a couple of seconds and then switch on again.

Last week I upgraded to windows 10 (from windows update, keeping data and applications) and it have the same issue (with no evident error in windows logs).

When I had windows 7 I reinstalled the machine a couple of time. Both the times, screen savers worked until the first machine reboot after the insallation ended, and then started to misbehave.

I also cloned the OS disk and boot it in a virtual machine, and I had the same behavior.

So... how can I pinpoint what is causing the problem?

Comment: Try unplugging any extra peripherals?  Perhaps there is some mouse/keyboard/etc that is constantly generating activity.

Comment: @patrickmdnet I'll try that, but I'm not confident, because when I start that OS in the virtual machine, I get the same problem, and in my VM settings there are no forwarded devices (beside keyboard and mouse, that are routed by the system).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have admin access or is it a company issued laptop? If it's the latter a lot of sys admins prevent personal screensavers.

If its your own laptop go to Regedit. There are quite a few settings that can be changed for this specific problem.

Comment: It's one of my personal machines (it's a desktop machine, not a laptop).